# Doublebyte encodings on MSVC (std::codecvt): Lead bytes not recognized

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, unicode, character-encoding

I want to convert a string encoded in a doublebyte code page into an UTF-16 string using [`std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>::in()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt/in) on the Microsoft standard library implementation (MSVC11). For example, consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    // KATAKANA LETTER A (U+30A2) in Shift-JIS (Codepage 932)
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305152
    char const cs[] = "\x83\x41";

    std::locale loc = std::locale("Japanese");

    // Output: "Japanese_Japan.932" (as expected)
    std::cout << loc.name() << '\n';

    typedef std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t> cvt_t;
    cvt_t const& codecvt = std::use_facet<cvt_t>(loc);
    wchar_t out = 0;
    std::mbstate_t mbst = std::mbstate_t();
    char const* mid;
    wchar_t* outmid;

    // Output: "2" (error) (expected: "0" (ok))
    std::cout << codecvt.in(
        mbst, cs,   cs + 2,   mid,
              &out, &out + 1, outmid) << '\n';

    // Output: "0" (expected: "30a2")
    std::cout << std::hex << out << '\n';
}
```

When debugging, I found out that `in()` ends up calling the internal `_Mbrtowc()` function (crt\src\xmbtowc.c), passing the internal (C?) part of the `std::locale`, initialized with `{_Page=932 _Mbcurmax=2 _Isclocale=0 ...}`, where ... stands for (and this seems to be the problem) the `_Isleadbyte` member, initialized to an array of 32 zeros (of type unsigned char). Thus, when the function processes the `'\x32'` lead byte, it checks with this array and naturally comes to the (wrong) conclusion that this is *not* a lead byte. So it happily calls the `MultiByteToWideChar()` Win-API function, which, of course, fails to convert the halfed character. So, `_Mbrtowc()` returns the error code -1, which more or less cancels everything up the call stack and ultimately the 2 (`std::codecvt_base::result::error`) is returned.

Is this a bug in the MS standard library (it seems so)? (How) can I work around this in a portable way (i.e. with the least amount of `#ifdef`s)?

Comment: I repro.  Very ugly code to debug, report this connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported it internally to Microsoft. The have now filled it as a new bug (DevDiv#737880). But I recomment to fill out a connect item at: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I am not directly affected by this bug, I found it when trying to create a minimal example for a related (3rd party library) bug. But think I will take the time and file a connect bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like I can't file a bug: I'm stuck in a loop where I'm repeatedly asked to complete my required profile information: connect.microsoft.com "Complete your required profile information" --(Next)--> social.microsoft.com "Edit My Profile" --(Save)--> profile.microsoft.com "Register" --(Next)--> (back to start).   Of course, I have filled in all required (*) fields.

Answer (score 1):

I copy pasted your code in VC2010 / Windows 7 64-bit.

It works as you expect. Here's the output:

```
Japanese_Japan.932
0
30a2
```

It's probably a bug introduced with VC2012...